# Can I set timeout for HtmlUnit.getWidth() on underlying image download requests

Tags: timeout, htmlunit

Question is: How can i set a timeout before I call HtmlImage.getHeight or getWidth()?

Context:

I am using the HtmlUnit 2.10 to obtain the actual image size of a  element and I am able to force the file download to occur. The call which is said to fire the image download is 
HtmlImage.getHeight() or getWidth(). However it seems that in certain cases (maybe when the site is slow or something...) it takes 15 minutes for this call to return and, while it seems to recover ok, I dont really want to interrupt the thread either.
Below a threaddump looks like this for whole duration of this 15 minutes process.

Test URL for the problem:
http://www.bbc.co.uk/zhongwen/simp/chinese_news/2012/10/121006_feature_china_highway_jams.shtml

```
"R-pool-5-thread-19" daemon prio=10 tid=0x525d4400 nid=0x4400 runnable [0x513c7000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:166)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:90)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:281)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:254)
at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:289)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:300)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:127)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:172)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1460)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1379)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.downloadImageIfNeeded(HtmlImage.java:374)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.readImageIfNeeded(HtmlImage.java:381)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlImage.getHeight(HtmlImage.java:311)
```